# A problem about partition of the set $\{1,2,..,n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I have a problem from my sister's studies:  Find the minimum number $n$ such that, for every partition of the set $X=\{1,2,...,n\}$ into three non-empty subsets, there always exist two numbers $a$ and $b$ in the same subset with $|a-b|$ a square number.

I'm a bit not good of this kind of math, thank for your help.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?

Comment: i tried to find the number n, this is an homework exercise of my sister :|

Answer (score 1):

This is really a graph theory question.  Given $n$, let $G(n)$ be the graph with vertices $1$ to $n$ and edges $(i, i+k^2)$ for positive integers $k$ such that $i+k^2 \le n$.
What is the smallest $n$ such that the chromatic number of $G(n)$ is greater than $3$.

I don't know if there's an easy way to do it by hand, but using Maple I find the answer is $29$.

Here's a picture of the case $n=28$ with vertices coloured red, green, blue corresponding to a partition where $|a-b|$ for $a$ and $b$ in the same subset is never a square.

[image]

Comment: my sister are studying about combinatorics so i think there are another way to solve, but thank you for your answer :D